# Web-based customisable editor for apache-camel spring xml routes

Tags: spring, apache-camel, hawtio, jboss-forge

In one of my projects I need ability to edit camel spring xml as the part of existing web application. There are set of just web-based xml editors. There are some work is done as part of hawtio camel plugin. Forge is on the way. But they all is not ready to be easy reused externally as I see. Maybe I am wrong and missed something?

Ideally will be to have following features supported:

- Online editing of camel spring xml which contains camel contexts/routes.
- Possibility to validate xml content (not only using schema). I know that such validation is in progress as part of forge addon, but maybe there are some other ways?
- Possibility to display xml as diagram (hawtio contains some implementation, but it's not ideal). If editing will be also possible it will be great, but I don't believe it's real now.

Answer (score 2):

1. What level of online editing are you looking for? Do you want a graphical drag/drop environment, or is a text based editor, that may have some level of Camel editing capabilities?

   For the drag/drop then there is a Camel editor in hawtio v1, in the wiki plugin. There is a standalone project here: https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio-camel-wiki that showcases this. However we just started working on a hawtio v2 Camel editor as part of the fabric8 project, where you have drag/drop and properties panel and all that stuff you have in a Eclipse like editor.
2. For validation then there is work on some Camel commands that can validate your routes in java/xml for invalid endpoint options / simple expression mistakes etc. A Maven Plugin has just been developed that can run this as part of a Maven build: https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8/tree/master/forge/addons/camel-maven-plugin
3. Yeah hawtio can display all your running Camel routes. And as said in #1 there is editing too (but in v1 its limited and not as much in use).

Its open source so anyone is surely welcome to help. We love contributions.

Comment: Hi Claus,
Thank you for your answer. Ideally we need both editing levels. Simplified graphical one with drag and drop and advanced text-based. But I am not sure there is an graphical one that can be used according to our internal requirements. So text-based will be good choice for the beginning.
I know about hawtio v1 camel plugin but it is very limited so I hope v2 will be good choice. What about validation and other camel/forge commands can you help me to understand is there a possibility to run them from the web app (not via command line)? Some kind of rest api etc.?

Comment: Btw, is it possible or planned to be possible to use hawtio v2 camel editor separately from the rest of the hawtio? Like running hawtio v2 with only camel plugin installed (custom build)? And use it to edit provided document?

Comment: Also can you point me to some documentation if any about hawtio v2? A seen a lot of related repos in hawtio github account and just some information on the site. I know that it currently in progress of active development.